# Get Error messages from Youtube using Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I am developing windows 8 application using YouTube API and C#. Now i need to display the same error message what youtube player displays on video failed. For example like this,

[image]

Is there any API query available to get this error message or any other best way to done this...??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the actual text of the message like that, but you can tell when it's been triggered; use the gdata feed for the video and specifically search for the media:restriction element, like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/zYNNPfuAHa4?fields=media:group/media:restriction
```

It will give you a list of countries where the above error message would be triggered; something like this:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<media:group>
<media:restriction type="country" relationship="deny">PR GU VI CA DE US UM AS MP PM</media:restriction>
</media:group>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing back YouTube content from your application, you should be using one of the official YouTube players (like the [iframe embedded player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)), in which case the player itself will take care of handling playback restrictions and displaying UX messages.